# Does compiler generate vtable for a class that is not used

Tags: c++, gcc

Can you explain does compiler generates vtable for a class which has virtual function and there is no use of that class(object not created in any sort). Say for ex,

```
    class A {
          public:
           virtual void func() { }
    };
    int main()
    {
       return 0;
    }
```

For the above program does compiler creates vtable for the class A?
It may be a duplicate question, but i wanted to know the solution. If it is duplicate please provide the link to the source.

Comment: If you look at the generated assembly of your example in http://gcc.godbolt.org/, you'll see that nothing is generated.

Comment: The compiler may generate it, but the linker won't link it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not good at understanding asm code. Is there possible to get the symbol table output. i dont have any compiler in machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a vtable is an implementation detail, and not part of the C++ standard. When a vtable is needed by your compiler, one is created.

In your case, the class is never used, and compilers won't generate any code at all.

But even if you instantiate the class and call functions with side-effects, if you never use features that necessitate a vtable, one does not need to be generated.

Comment: Does the `sizeof` the class contain the vtable pointer even if the vtable is optimized out?

Comment: I'd presume that if the class is declared in a header file, the compiler is going to generate it in case it's used elsewhere. Whether the linker then drops it is another question.

Comment: Although tagged for gcc, for completness-sake MSVC uses `__declspec(novftable)` to force removal of the vtable (as ctor's and dtor's will keep refs to the vtable, even if no virtual functions are needed, preventing DCE from removing it): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky.aspx Of course if the class is never used the linker will strip the vtable.

Comment: For internal linkage, a compiler could certainly elide vtable (also from `sizeof`). For external linkage, the compiler will likely prepare for it and the linker will discard it. In that case, `sizeof` I assume includes the (unused) vtable.

Comment: @Necrolis it's `novtable`. And I always assumed that also made the class not include vtable pointer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: right you are, shouldn't type those from memory (unfortunately I can't edit the comment, but the link is correct). From an empirical test (using VS2013), it doesn't generate a vtable, but the class will still have an uninitialized *vtable slot*, thus the size will not change.

Answer (score 3):

I've spent some time in the [gcc.godbolt.org service](http://gcc.godbolt.org)  (thanks @RudolfsBundulis a lot for it) in trying out what cases will make compiler to generate the virtual table to satisfy my curiosity.

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual void func() { }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        void func() final override {};
};

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Any declaration of abstract classes and even their implementations will not make compiler to create everything (even these classes!). But, this also depends on compiler's optimization level:

1. `-O1` on any compiler generates with such main:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       A *a = new B;
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. `-O2` allows to generate `vtable` and other stuff but not for any compiler. I've checked latest clang (3.6, 3.7) and gcc (4.9.2, 5.1.0) and it is generated only by `gcc 4.9.2`.
3. `-O3` on clang (3.6, 3.7), gcc (5.1.0) does not generate anything. But, they do so unless you have a actual call:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       A *a = new B;
       a->func();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   But note that `gcc 4.9.2` still generates it even with `-O3` and without the call `a->func()`!

So, the answer did not change from what @tenfour said - it is really compiler-dependent and depends on it's optimization levels and even a version of a compiler.
In this research it was really interesting that `gcc 4.9.2` still compiles it while it is not really needed, though this behaviour is fixed in `gcc 5.1.0`.

Comment: Can you please help me to check(verify) that does gcc/clang with different versions generates vtable for the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `vtable for the problem` ? I've thought I just clarified when vtable is generated..

Comment: For case 3, you said that gcc 4.9.2 generates vtable. Can you please share how you have checked that vtable is created in gcc.godbolt.org?

Comment: Just paste my code there and try to find `vtable` sections in the asm code.

Comment: @Saravanan did some of answers help you? If yes, please mark it accept, so the readers of your question can know the solution.